# grub stopped during start-up

Tags: boot, startup, reboot

I have only Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell Inspiron 3593 laptop,
but every restart or power the device doesn't continue and I need to force restart until Ubuntu opens.

[image]

Comment: The grub shown in that picture is **NOT** a Ubuntu 22.04 system, *jammy* (22.04) uses `2.06-2ubuntu7.1` but your picture shows a `grub` installed from a system likely four years (*or more*) older... ie. you have dual boot system with another *installed* OS controlling your boot process.  If your system has multiple drives it maybe a *firmware* setting that has changed, if another OS was installed it took over control etc... ie. details we've not been provided are where you'll need to look.

Comment: FYI:  If you had another OS installed, which has been removed - that will be your answer (the removed OS controlled the booting process; you should have made your Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system take ownership of boot (ie. use it's grub 2.06) before removing the other OS).  Again we've not been told specifics as to changes that were made in the session(s) before this problem occurred which created the issue (*the OS as stated is from 2018 or before given 2.02 in photo*)

Comment: actually this picture i got from internet but my OS is ubuntu 22.10 and grub version is 2.06 as you suggest
my laptop has two hard disk 
first one SSD and i was formated and install ubuntu on it 
second one HDD and i was formate it after install ubuntu from DIsk application
this hard has two partitions and i reformat them 
but i see another unlocated space about 1.06 mib 
and until now i see grub screen every reboot and must repeat restarting device until continue to OS